# Cannot deploy/serve Firebase with error: No "exports" main defined in package.json

Tags: node.js, firebase

'firebase' npm package is used in Functions backend for
.initializeApp(config) and
.Auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

Firebase deploy/serve throws this error:

```bash
+  functions: Using node@16 from host.
i  functions: Watching "C:\Users\ewert\Documents\Study\Udemy\Authentication\Firebase Practice\functions" for Cloud Functions...        
!!  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in C:\Users\ewert\Documents\Study\Udemy\Authentication\Firebase Practice\functions\node_modules\firebase\package.json
```

Re-installing firebase package, updating Node, npm and using 'firebase-admin' did not solve the issue.

Tutorial [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-todo-application-using-reactjs-and-firebase/), step Section 2.1

Firebase version: 11.7.0

I'm very thankful if you can help.

Comment: It would be helpful to see which version of firebase you have installed, as the problem seems to be with firebase being called in 'users.js'. So it would also be helpful to see the code in 'users.js'. However, I suspect the problem is having firebase@9 installed when you are trying to write code with firebase@8.

Comment: I think you are using the new firebase version. edit firebase npm version to ^7.13.1 in pakage.json file and reinstall it.

Comment: if you are following the freeCodeCamp how-to-build-a-todo-application-using-reactjs-and-firebase article, it is likely that you are encountering an issue where they wrote that article in firebase web version 8.x and you are using version 9.x.  They changed from namespaced to modular for various (good) reasons.  See this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#web-version-9_1

Comment: Maybe require is not working for the latest version. I just reinstall it with a lower version like ^7.13.1 as @MuhammedAnasU suggested. Then it worked fine for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

The Firebase js sdk is for client-side use only. In order to interact with Firebase from your backend environment (ie cloud functions, node backend, etc), you must use the admin-sdk.

Keep in mind that since the admin-sdk runs in a secure, trusted environment, it has elevated privileges and will bypass security rules, so make sure you're validating your data in your functions.

You can view the full documentation for the admin-sdk here: [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin)

Comment: The tutorial I was following uses it to firebase..Auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(). And when I look for how to use firebase-admin, I found firebase package can be used for user authentication. Do you mean I should do authentication from frontend to firebase authentication, instead of going through functions?

Comment: @SupathiRatnayake signInWithEmailAndPassword() is a function in the client sdk (mobile, web, etc) and thus must be used in your frontend code. If you're able to provide further examples of your code and use case then we can give you better answers

Comment: So I have a library that works with `firebase` and `firebase-admin` and it's used in both the front-end and the back-end. It references both. How can I solve this error?