# Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" - Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, express

Working through this [Full Stack React & Firebase Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_u6P5k0vP0) and trying to use Firebase Authentication, to create a new user,  I am getting the below error.

```
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in /socialapp-functions/functions/node_modules/firebase/package.json
    at throwExportsNotFound (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:299:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:522:3)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:449:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:489:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/socialapp-functions/functions/index.js:17:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
⚠  We were unable to load your functions code. (see above)
```

The tutorial details code like this:

```
// Signup route
app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  const newUser = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
    handle: req.body.handle,
  };

  firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
    .then((data) => {
      return res
        .status(201)
        .json({ message: `user ${data.user.uid} signed up successfully` });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per the question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68944045/16743381) I think the issue is the tutorial has code for Firebase@8 when I'm running Firebase@9.

Referencing the Firebase Admin SDK docs to [Manage Users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users), I am using

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
```

Instead of

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
```

I updated my code to the below and can now successfully add users on a POST.

```
// Signup route
app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  const newUser = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
    handle: req.body.handle,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    name: req.body.name,
    photoURL: req.body.photo,
  };

  admin
    .auth()
    .createUser({
      email: newUser.email,
      emailVerified: false,
      phoneNumber: newUser.phone,
      password: newUser.password,
      displayName: newUser.name,
      photoURL: newUser.photoURL,
      disabled: false,
    })
    .then((data) => {
      return res
        .status(201)
        .json({ message: `user ${data.uid} signed up successfully` });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

In **June 2022**

In Node js

The permanent solution to all my problems was **uninstalling the firebase v9+**

Next i did:

```
npm uninstall firebase
```

then

```
npm i firebase@8.6.8
```

Hope this solves your issue too

Edit: Also u won't be requiring firebase-admin after this

Comment: Thank you! very underrated solution!

Answer (score 3):

With these versions it works!! Downgrade/upgrade these dependencies to match the following in <package.json>

```
"dependencies": {
"firebase": "^8.10.0",
"firebase-admin": "^8.13.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"
},
```

Comment: I don't know why but it works.

Comment: @ViacheslavDobromyslov it works because the suggested answer is using the older Firebase SDK

Answer (score 1):

The way you do this using Firebase SDK changed with the new [version 9](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

Instead of

```
const firebase = require("firebase");

firebase
.auth()
.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
.then((data) => {
  return res
    .status(201)
    .json({ message: `user ${data.user.uid} signed up successfully` });
})
```

Do this

```
const { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } = require( "firebase/auth");

const auth = getAuth();
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
.then((data) => {
  return res
    .status(201)
    .json({ message: `user ${data.user.uid} signed up successfully` });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

just install **xhr2** in your node_modules, and use **firebase-admin** instead of firebase then try.