# firebase install and node

Tags: node.js, firebase, discord

I have a little problem here in my discord.js v13 bot project with Firebase. Below will be the code and error

```
const firebase = require('firebase')

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBEV2nNoeVe_60sgUIbJ--kx6eo1Ni1OFw",
  authDomain: "kayo-bot.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "kayo-bot",
  storageBucket: "kayo-bot.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "494266519381",
  appId: "1:494266519381:web:778871f3fcc24dd3dae9dc"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var database = firebase.database()
```

error:

```
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:488
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in /home/runner/Kayo/node_modules/firebase/package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:440:9)
 npx node index.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:488
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in /home/runner/Kayo/node_modules/firebase/package.json
```

I installed firebase properly.

Comment: Please translate the title too

Comment: See [Error ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69200493/205233) and other existing questions regarding that error message.